# C++ / C# ABC design pattern with static member

Tags: c#, c++, templates, static-members

I have an ABC class I want to make generic:

```
struct BinaryVariable {
  static const int N = 2;
  static std::string outcome_names[N] = { "heads", "tails" };
};

struct EvidenceBinaryVariable : public BinaryVariable {
  double likelihoods[ BinaryVariable::N ];
};

struct LatentBinaryVariable : public BinaryVariable { };
```

The important thing is that every instance of these three nodes shares the same `::N`, and uses the same memory for the `outcome_names` variable.

Let's say I want to make these three node types to also allow for a variable with 6 possible outcomes (i.e. I want to support dice in addition to coins). In C++ I can do this with templates:

```
#include<cstddef>
#include<string>

template<std::size_t N>
struct DiscreteVariable {
  static std::string outcome_names[N];
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct EvidenceVariable : public DiscreteVariable<N> {
  double likelihoods[ DiscreteVariable::N ];
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct LatentVariable : public DiscreteVariable<N> { };

int main()
{
    LatentVariable<2> schrodingers_coin;
    LatentVariable<6> schrodingers_die;
}
```

I can't figure out a way to get the three types to have a static `outcome_names` member (and where `shrodingers_coin.outcome_names` and `schrodingers_dice.outcome_names` do not refer to the same static piece of memory) without using templates in this way.

C# only supports type-based templates (i.e. you could provide `<int>` but not `<6>`.

First question: is there a good design pattern for this in C++? (e.g. should I use these triplets as internal classes within a master class?)

Second question: does this good design pattern work in C# (or is C++'s template magic just a good fit here)?

Just for posterity, the reason I want these static is because I have tons of these objects, and am writing something where efficiency is paramount (think big data).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: OP: I edited your C++ code to at least make it valid code.

Comment: Few questions.  First, should `LatentVariable<2> foo;` and `LatentVaraible<2> bar;` point to the same `DiscreteVariable` string array?  If not, then you don't want `outcome_names[]` to be static.  Second, this is an example of when composition makes more sense than inheritance; `DiscreteVariable`, or rather `outcome_names[]` should be a (probably nonstatic depending on the answer to the first question) member of `LatentVariable`.

Comment: @Aggieboy I would like them to refer to the same memory (the names of the variables should should be the same for all objects of a given size, and I want to avoid having one copy per item). Regarding inheritance, to me this really is an "Is a" type of dependency, but maybe you're saying this could make maintenance simpler with composition? How?

Comment: @NeilKirk enum would be a good idea, but I want to be able to iterate through the outcome names: `cout << outcome_names[i] << " had likelihood " << likelihoods[i];`

Comment: If your enums are consecutive (0, 1, 2..) and you call the last enum name_max or something, you can iterate 0 < name_max and cast the int to your enum. Or you can push the enums into a vector in whatever order you like at the start of day.

Comment: I've never seen this `EvidenceVariable` terminology before, but your `DiscreteVariable` is somewhat of a misnomer because it should have an `outcome_name` *and* a `likelihood` array.  The "is a vs has a" question is somewhat misleading otherwise.  This also implies that `EvidenceVariable` and `LatentVariable` are just typedefs of your `DiscreteVariable`.  This is all besides the point however; templates are used to generate nearly identical code.  In your case, each template class will need to be specialized for each array initialization, so why use templates?  Your first example seemed good.

Comment: Variables do not have likelihoods unless you have evidence. That is why all variables are classified into two sub-types: latent (no observed evidence, and thus no likelihood table) and variables with evidence (where there are likelihoods available). If I say I flipped a coin, you don't know if it's a fair flip (there's a machine at Stanford that always gets heads). So you can't guarantee that it's prior probabilities are 50/50 (although there is still some Bayesian rationale to do so). If you know that the coin gives 60/40, you can encode that.

Answer (score 0):

Your DiscreteVariable class is just an enum, so use an enum. This is how I would implement this in C#:

```
enum SchrodingersCoin
{
    Heads,
    Tails,
}

class Likelihood<T>
{
    public static double[] likelihoods;

    static Likelihood()
    {
        // Init likelihoods here using Enum.GetValues()
    }
}
```

C++ implementation:

```
enum SchrodingersCoin
{
    Head,
    Tails,
    Count,
};

template <typename T>
struct Likelihood
{
    static double likelihoods[T::Count];
};
```

In C# you can easily convert enums to strings, but in C++ you usually have to write a function to do the conversion for you.